# Open source alternatives to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uikit

Which open source alternatives to UIScrollView is there?

I need `paging` so it would be awesome if we could categorize by that feature.

I'm looking for alternatives for the sole reason that Apple recommends against putting UIWebView inside UIScrollView. More specifically I experience problems with `fixed`content on iOS 5. But let's stick to the question: alternatives to UIScrollView.

Comment: I did not understand your problem. If you need paging the UIScrollView has already that feature, you need to set the property pagingEnabled to YES. Apple does not recommend using nested scrollviews, which can be scrolled in same direction because of usability (Maybe another reasons too). So if you use some other scroll views which has another name, it does not change your situation.

Comment: @Mert I'm full aware of that property, thank you :) Please stick to the question.

Comment: UIWebView now has access to the internal UIScrollView

Comment: @Nick Yep, UIWebView got a scrollView, but I'm not talking about that scrollview. What's difficult by sticking to the question? Other people might come look for answers to this question for other reasons than webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check TTScrollView, part of the famous Three20 framework.
https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTScrollView.h

---

[Edited 2013-09-16]

[CHScrollView](https://github.com/haifengkao/CHScrollView) is another open source alternative of UIScrollView. It is written by myself :)

Comment: That's actually an alternative! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make something like photo gallery, but web views instead photos, you can use UIPageViewController which shows webviews.

Comment: UIPageViewController uses UIScrollView doesen't it?

Comment: @hfossli Apple has an example code, UIPageViewController shows UIScrollViews, which can be found here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 0):

Check out DDPageControl

https://github.com/ddeville/DDPageControl

For more controls just search on http://cocoacontrols.com

Comment: That's an alternative to UIPageControl, not UIScrollView